# Why does git push works for one repo and doesn't work for the other? git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github

I used GPG to set my Github access. I created new repo today and I encountered problems like this

```
git push origin main
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.999.4' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Remote

```
git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:balboa/createreactapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:balboa/createreactapp.git (push)
```

Everything works fine from my other repo

```
git commit -m "signup changed"
[master b590077] signup changed
 3 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

How to solve permission for the new repo?

Comment: You need to inspect the `.git/config`, `~/.gitconfig` and `~/.ssh/config` files to see where it specifies which ssh key to use for the respective library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis issue can be happened  if you dont add your  public key to ssh-agent after RSA key generation

First ,
Add your required public key ( ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub )
to your github Account then ,

This problem can be solved by running these commands

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<required-key>.pub
```

This will add your public key to ssh-agent and  it wont show the error message of 'Could not read from remote repository.'